# match xml entities in reqex using xml::dom

Tags: xml, perl, entity

I have a script that loops through all text nodes in an xml file (using xml::dom) and then mathces them against a reqex. I am failing to make a match for text such as:

```
&#xa7;&#x2009;1-101
```

I am unable to make a match with a regex such as

```
my $match =~ qr/((?:\&\#xa7;\&\#x2009\;)?(?:\d+\-\d{3}))/;
```

it works ok when I omit the entities...my best (limited) guess is that the entities are not simple text and that I need code to either flatten the entities into plain text, or handle the entities somehow. What is the best way to handle that issue?

Answer (score 0):

XML::DOM::Node has a non-standard method, expandEntityRefs(), that expands those into plaintext.  Otherwise, HTML::Entities might also be good enough for your use.